# Inconsistent phantom space in table p column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, phantom

Follow-up from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392698/align-emails-in-table).

### Issue

`phantom` seems to have an inconsistent behaviour depending on whether something is printed before its call when used in a `p` column type in a table.

- When used on its own, it generates a linebreak;
- When highlighted with `colorbox` it fixes itself but generates 2 extra characters (spaces);
- When prefixed by a negative `hspace`, it works properly but this does not seem right;
- When used with both `colorbox` and `hspace`, another extra space appears.

### Bonus question

In my `newcolumntype` definition, I use `textwidth` to define the width of the columns but this does not take into account `tabcolsep`. Is there a way to somehow redefine it to be `\textwidth-\tabcolsep`?

### Demo

[image: demo]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\newcommand{\mail}[1]{
  \href{mailto:#1}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\centering

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L{.03}|L{.5}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{w/ phantom} \\
  \midrule
  1           & {\ttfamily\phantom{xxx}\mail{a@tex.c}}   \\
  2           & {\ttfamily\phantom{xx}\mail{ab@tex.co}}  \\
  3           & {\ttfamily\mail{abcd@tex.com}}           \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L{.03}|L{.5}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{w/ colorbox} \\
  \midrule
  1           & {\ttfamily\colorbox{red}{\phantom{xxx}}\mail{a@tex.c}}  \\
  2           & {\ttfamily\colorbox{red}{\phantom{xx}}\mail{ab@tex.co}} \\
  3           & {\ttfamily\mail{abcd@tex.com}}                          \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L{.03}|L{.5}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{w/ hspace} \\
  \midrule
  1           & {\ttfamily\hspace{-.5em}\phantom{xxx}\mail{a@tex.c}}  \\
  2           & {\ttfamily\hspace{-.5em}\phantom{xx}\mail{ab@tex.co}} \\
  3           & {\ttfamily\hspace{-.5em}\mail{abcd@tex.com}}          \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L{.03}|L{.5}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{w/ hspace \& colorbox} \\
  \midrule
  1           & {\ttfamily\hspace{-.5em}\colorbox{red}{\phantom{xxx}}\mail{a@tex.c}}  \\
  2           & {\ttfamily\hspace{-.5em}\colorbox{red}{\phantom{xx}}\mail{ab@tex.co}} \\
  3           & {\ttfamily\hspace{-.5em}\mail{abcd@tex.com}}                          \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\leavevmode\phantom{xxx}`

Comment: note this is not related to phantom specifically, try with `\hbox{zzz}` as opposed to `\mbox{zzz}` If you use low level commands in a latex context then you have to take care of more primitive tex behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer (Edited to use `hbox` instead of `mbox` as @David Carlisle suggests) Also added `\arraystretch` fix**

This is a way to avoid all the problems of your way and to automate
all the process. You have to use the columns as on my code (r@{}>{@}l or similar) and to give
in your tabular the commands: `\nameMAIL{nameHere}` and `\MAILon{providerHere}`. It already creates what you want without counting spaces that would be bad in result if a number like 1 was inside the mail name. (x is longer than 1 or than `l`->small L). So, to avoid all this things you are already ok with these commands. But For your example needed a link too. So I used `\tikzmark` (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35718/120578)) and created the command `LinkAllMails`. Just don't forget to set it's counter (`numOfmails`) to zero before starting a new tabular. Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\makeatletter
\xdef\myfsize{\f@size}
\makeatother


\newcounter{numOfmails}


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\nameMAIL}[1]{\stepcounter{numOfmails}\tikzmark{MAIL\thenumOfmails}\xdef\temp{#1}\global\expandafter\let\csname Mail\thenumOfmails\endcsname\temp\hbox{\phantom{\temp}}}
\newcommand{\MAILon}[1]{\xdef\temp{#1}\global\expandafter\let\csname MAILon\thenumOfmails\endcsname\temp\hbox{\phantom{\temp}}\tikzmark{MAILon\thenumOfmails}}

\newcommand{\LinkAllMails}{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\foreach \i in {1,...,\thenumOfmails}{
\path  ($(MAIL\i.north west)+(0,{\myfsize/1.5 pt})$) rectangle node[anchor=center] (NODE\i){} ($(MAILon\i.south east)$);
\node at (NODE\i) {\href{mailto:\csname Mail\i\endcsname@\csname MAILon\i\endcsname}{\csname Mail\i\endcsname\phantom{@}\csname MAILon\i\endcsname}};}\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}



\begin{document}
\centering

\noindent

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{tabular}{L{.03}|r@{}>{@}L{0.5}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{\#} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{w/ phantom}}\\
  \midrule
  1     & \nameMAIL{wab}&\MAILon{gmail.com}\\
  2     & \nameMAIL{1ab}&\MAILon{gmail.com}\\
  3           &\nameMAIL{ab}&\MAILon{gmail.com}\\
  4           &\nameMAIL{abdul}&\MAILon{hotmail.com}\\
  5           &\nameMAIL{koleygr}&\MAILon{private.com}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\LinkAllMails


\setcounter{numOfmails}{0}
\begin{tabular}{L{.03}|r@{}>{@}L{0.5}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{\#} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{w/ phantom}}\\
  \midrule
  6     & \nameMAIL{wa7b1}&\MAILon{gmail.com}\\
  7     & \nameMAIL{1ab}&\MAILon{gmail.com}\\
  8           &\nameMAIL{3ab}&\MAILon{gmail.com}\\
  9           &\nameMAIL{abdu5l}&\MAILon{hotmail.com}\\
  10           &\nameMAIL{koleygr}&\MAILon{nottooprivate.com}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\LinkAllMails


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

**Old answer:**

According to @egreg's comment the `\mbox` command already "gives" a `\leavemode` and so there is no reason for the `\leavemode` in front of the `\mbox` command. (I just leaving it as is for now).

Check this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\newcommand{\mail}[1]{%
\href{mailto:#1}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L{.03}|L{.5}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{w/ phantom}\\
  \midrule
  1           &\leavevmode\mbox{\ttfamily\phantom{xxx}\mail{a@tex.c}}\\
  2           &\leavevmode\mbox{\ttfamily\phantom{xx}\mail{ab@tex.co}}\\
  3           &\leavevmode\mbox{\ttfamily\mail{abcd@tex.com}}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{L{.03}|L{.5}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{w/ phantom}\\
  \midrule
  1           &\leavevmode\mbox{\ttfamily{\color{red}xxx}\mail{a@tex.c}}\\
  2           &\leavevmode\mbox{\ttfamily{\color{red}xx}\mail{ab@tex.co}}\\
  3           &\leavevmode\mbox{\ttfamily\mail{abcd@tex.com}}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You had the next problems:

1. According to the selected answer of the question [\phantom inside tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106584/120578) you have to add a `\leavemode` command to use phantom inside your tabular.
2. Your command for the `\mail` had some tokens that created extra space.
3. You can use an `\mbox` to avoid extra space of the heperref function for the mail.

   Output:

[image]

Comment: `\mbox` does `\leavevmode`, so it's not necessary to add it.

Comment: Thanks @egreg... I did it step by step for his mistakes and did not realized that. I will edit.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because all that was required to fix my issues was to remove the spaces added by the `mail` command definition (add `%` to the line breaks...). Your code might be overkill for this purpose but it is a nice hack. That being said, you could have stuck with `ttfamily` to avoid letter spacing issues, and it requires to split the address in two columns which causes issues if someone were to try and copy and paste the data from the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a simple fix to the issue described, there is only two steps to take:

1. Add `%` to the line breaks in the `mail` command definition to avoid extra space;
2. Use `leavevmode` to stack blocks horizontally and prevent line breaks in the table.

#### Demo

[image: demo]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\newcommand{\mail}[1]{%
  \href{mailto:#1}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L{.03}|L{.5}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{\#} & \textbf{w/ phantom \& leavevmode} \\
  \midrule
  1           & {\leavevmode\ttfamily\phantom{xxx}\mail{a@tex.c}}   \\
  2           & {\leavevmode\ttfamily\phantom{xx}\mail{ab@tex.co}}  \\
  3           & {\leavevmode\ttfamily\mail{abcd@tex.com}}           \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```