# Placing a cell separator (&) into tblr via command

Tags: tabularray

I'm trying to produce a table like this:
[image]

My code currently looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, BCOR=0mm, usegeometry]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.1cm, rmargin=2.1cm, bottom=3cm, footskip=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  row{1} = {black!20, font={\bfseries}},
  colspec = {|X[m]|X[m]|l|r@{}>{@}l|l|},
  hlines,
  cell{1}{4} = {c=2}{c},
}
Role        & Name                  & Tel-Nr.       & E-Mail &                          & Team\\
Apprentice  & Imogen Illustration   & 000 000 00 00 & imogen.illustration&example.info  & Example Team 1 \\
Instructor  & Eric Example          & 000 000 00 00 & eric.example&example.info         & Example Team 1 \\
Expert      & Sean Sample           & 000 000 00 00 & sean.sample&exmpl.org             & Exmpl Org  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Now I'd like to replace how the emails are typeset from `sean.sample&exmpl.org` to `\mail{sean.sample@exmpl.org}` and defining something like this:

```latex
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mail}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{@}}m}{%
  \mailprocessor #1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mailprocessor}{m m}{%
  \commandA{#1} & \commandB{#2}%
}
```

But LaTeX complains about the ampersand. [This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338918) works for `tabular` and `tabularx`, but the error remains when sticking to `tblr`/`tabularray`.

(ultimately I want to pass the arguments on to the solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393492) for aligning hyperlinked email-addresses along the @ sign, though I'm open for other solutions of doing that alignment and still have the links work)

Anyway, how can I get that ampersand to be accepted somehow?

Comment: You would have to tell `tblr` to expand the macro that generates the `&`, like `\begin{tblr}[expand=\mail]`, but you must also make sure that this also expands `\mailprocessor`.

Comment: This post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648904/misplaced-alignment-tab-character-with-tabularray-and-expl3 can help you